# how to block certain users by machine name in remote desktop?

Tags: windows, windows-server

I have a scenario where a common user can be connected from multiple machines, i.e,

login: analysis.lhr

users from multiple machines can use this login to connect to servers using remote desktop. All I want is that only those users whose machine name is white listed can use the login analysis.lhr to connect to servers.

Answer (score 0):

That's not the way god intend it to be. You should better give unique name to each user, but put some of them to a group analysis.grp. Thus you will be able to grant access to users who are in group analysis.grp.